# Spring Data Rest output join column object as JSON field when querying single resource

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have Apartment entity:

```
@Entity
public class Apartment extends AbstractEntity {

private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@RestResource(exported = false)
private Address address;

private String website;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "apartment")
@RestResource(exported = false)
private Set<FloorPlan> floorPlans;
...
```

FloorPlan entity:

```
@Entity
public class FloorPlan extends AbstractEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "apt_id", nullable = false)
private Apartment apartment;
private float bed;
private float bath;
private int priceFrom;
...
```

I applied excerptProjection to Floorplan to only show bed, bath and priceFrom. When I query apartments collection, the json output looks ok:

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "apartments": [
        {
            "name": "Avalon Silicon Valley",
            "website": "https://www.avaloncommunities.com/california/sunnyvale-apartments/avalon-silicon-valley",
            "address": {
                "streetNumber": "1257",
                "street": "Lakeside Drive",
                "city": "Sunnyvale",
                "state": "CA",
                "zipCode": "94085",
                "fullAddress": "1257 Lakeside Drive, Sunnyvale, CA 94085"
            },
            "floorPlans": [
                {
                    "bed": 3,
                    "bath": 3,
                    "priceFrom": 4495
                },
                {
                    "bed": 3,
                    "bath": 2,
                    "priceFrom": 4760
                },
```

However if I do a single resource like http://localhost:8080/ag-api/apartments/1
floorplans will output Apartment Object as one of its field:

```
{
"name": "Avalon Silicon Valley",
"address": {
    "streetNumber": "1257",
    "street": "Lakeside Drive",
    "city": "Sunnyvale",
    "state": "CA",
    "zipCode": "94085",
    "fullAddress": "1257 Lakeside Drive, Sunnyvale, CA 94085"
},
"website": "https://www.avaloncommunities.com/california/sunnyvale-apartments/avalon-silicon-valley",
"floorPlans": [
    {
        "bed": 3,
        "bath": 3,
        "priceFrom": 4495,
        "_embedded": {
            "apartment": {
                "name": "Avalon Silicon Valley",
                "website": "https://www.avaloncommunities.com/california/sunnyvale-apartments/avalon-silicon-valley",
                "address": {
                    "streetNumber": "1257",
                    "street": "Lakeside Drive",
                    "city": "Sunnyvale",
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zipCode": "94085",
                    "fullAddress": "1257 Lakeside Drive, Sunnyvale, CA 94085"
                },
                "floorPlans": [
```

Anyone got an idea what might be going on? really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: This only happens if excerption is applied to Apartment, otherwise single resource looks ok

Comment: Is that an infinite loop? it usually happens when you serialize the object via standard JSON objectmapper. Are you sure it's rendered by standard data-rest endpoint? If yes pls append the projections and also the configuration.

Comment: I fixed it by implementing a custom controller with endpoint /{id} and make it return List<ApartmentProjection> seems to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but in documentation I found in order to omit "_embedded" in you response you'll need to add:

"spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false" to application.properties.